# plugin application giving a casting error

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, plugins, console-application

I created a Console application which **searches for plugins** ending with PlugIn.dll.
It **loads the dll assembly and executes the write** method of plugInClass in PlugIn.dll.
I created an interface called IWrite which includes the write method.
After executing the console app,it gives an error as given below:

***Unable to cast object of type 'HPlugIn.plugInClass' to type 'ConsolePlugIn.IWrite'.***

Here is my code for console app..[Main application]

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
namespace ConsolePlugIn
{
    interface IWrite
    {
        void write();
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "*PlugIn.dll"))//getting plugins in base directory
            {
                Assembly aWrite = Assembly.LoadFrom(s);
                Type tWrite = aWrite.GetType("HPlugIn.plugInClass");
                IWrite click = (IWrite)Activator.CreateInstance(tWrite);//giving casting error
                click.write();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

here is my code for the plugIn dll file

```
using System;
namespace HPlugIn
{
    interface IWrite
    {
        void write();
    }
    public class plugInClass : IWrite
    {
      public  void write()
        {
            Console.Write("High from plugInClass");
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea for this casting error?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IWrite` interfaces in the EXE and in the DLL are not the same, even though their structures are identical. You need to make a third dll with the interface, and share it among the DLLs and the EXE.

Common:

```
namespace Shared {
    interface IWrite {
        void write();
    }
}
```

DLL:

```
using System;
using Shared;
namespace HPlugIn {
    public class plugInClass : IWrite {
        public  void write() {
            Console.Write("High from plugInClass");
        }
    }
}
```

EXE:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using Shared;
namespace ConsolePlugIn {
    class Program {
        ...
    } 
}
```

Comment: ohh...so the identity of d interface needs to be the same for the dll as well as exe..right..

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the `IWrite` interface twice in 2 different assemblies. They are considered different types and you cannot cast from one to the other. The best way to achieve weaker coupling between the EXE and the assembly is to define this interface into a separate DLL. Then have the plugin and executable both reference this third assembly containing the contract (the `IWrite` interface).

Answer (score 1):

There are two different `IWrite` interfaces. One in the console app and one in the dll. There are two ways to work around this.

- Make the dll reference the console app and have `plugInClass` implement the `ConsolePlugIn.IWrite` interface.
- Use the `dynamic` keyword to make interfaces looking the same match.